# update statement error in image

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-update

```
private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] img1 = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Final Project Bridger\Bridger\Bridger\Images\20green.png");

    try
    {
        if (txtfno.Text == "" && txtslab.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Update not possible");
        }
        else
        {
            cnn.Open();
            cmd3.CommandText = "update Slab set indi = @img1 where s_flatno = @s_flatno and s_name = @s_name";

            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@indi",img1);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_flatno", txtfno.Text);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_name", txtslab.Text);

            cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        cnn.Close();
    }
}
```

In this code, I'm updating image in the position indi and I'm setting a new img1 in byte. While press update I'm getting an error

> Must declare scalar variable @img1

Comment: error solved....

Answer (score 1):

You have named your variable `@img1` in the SQL Statement, but `@indi` when you declared the variable.

Please note that best practice when handling `DBConnection` is as a local variable inside a `using` statement, and you better use one of the overloads of `Add` when adding parameters to a command instead of `AddWithValue`. For more information, read [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Here is an improved version of your code:

```
private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (txtfno.Text == "" && txtslab.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Updation not possible");
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {

            byte[] img1 = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Final Project Bridger\Bridger\Bridger\Images\20green.png");

            var sql = "update Slab set indi=@indi where s_flatno=@s_flatno and s_name=@s_name";
            // I'm assuming SQL Server based on the error message
            using(var cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@indi", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = img1;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@s_flatno", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtfno.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@s_name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtslab.Text;
                }
                cnn.Open();
                cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small issue with you code. You have not passed @img1 parameter. You are sending it as @indi. Either Change @img1 to @indi in sql query string or change @indi to @img1 in add parameter statement:

```
cnn.Open();
cmd3.CommandText = "update Slab set indi=@indi where s_flatno=@s_flatno and s_name=@s_name";
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@indi",img1);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_flatno", txtfno.Text);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_name", txtslab.Text);
cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
```